# JS addEventListener() confusion, seems to add recursively to children?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I'm working on a JS class for generating a responsive navigation bar and having trouble setting  the events which handle showing and hiding different elements at different times. The structure is defined in the following HTML.

```
<div class="menu-container" id="menu1">
    <div class="menu-label"> Menu 1 Label </div>
    <div class="menu-list-container">
        <div class="menu-item"> Item 1 </div>
        <div class="menu-item"> Item 2 </div>
        <div class="menu-item"> Item 3 </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    setListeners();
</script>
```

So we have a container, inside of that there is a label and a list container, and inside that list container is a list of menu items.

The goal is to toggle the `display` property of the `menu-list-container` between `none` and `block` based on mouse events. What I want, is to attach a `mouseover` event to the `menu-label` which "shows" the `menu-list`, i.e. sets `display: block` and then a `mouseout` event to the `menu-container` which obviously reverses the setting of `display`.

My JS to do this is below:

```
function setListeners(){
    var menCon = document.getElementById("menu1");//1 div
    var menLab = menCon.children[0];// 1 div
    var menList = menLab.nextElementSibling;//1 div
    var menItems = menList.children;// HTMLCollection
    console.log(menCon);
    console.log(menLab);
    console.log(menList);
    console.log(menItems);

    menLab.addEventListener("mouseover",showList,false);
    menCon.addEventListener("mouseout",hideList,false);
}

function showList(evt){
    var list = evt.target.nextElementSibling;
    list.style.display = "block";
}

function hideList(evt){
    console.log(evt.target)
    var list = evt.target.children.item(1);
    list.style.display = "none";
}
```

There's not any problem as far as I can tell with the `showList` listener function, but the `hideList` is causing me all kind of problems. While debugging I've noticed a few things: First, I thought the `menu-container` may not be resizing properly, but if FireFox developer tools are to be trusted, it is indeed resizing upon "showing" the `menu-list-container`; However, upon moving the mouse downward (from hovering over the `menu-label`) I can see the `hideList` function being called after exiting every individual element inside of the `menu-container` via the call to `console.log()` in that function. And indeed, the `evt.target` is those elements, meaning that the event listener is being activated by those elements AND NOT by the `menu-container` element, which is super confusing to me considering that I clearly attached the event to the container and nothing else. On top of that, in the FireFox inspector, you can see which elements have events attached to them, and it confirms that the `menu-container` element has a `mouseout` event and nothing else.

Clearly I've got a fundamental misunderstanding of how `addEventListener` works, but I can't seem to understand why what I'm doing is working the way it does. I could use some enlightenment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`mouseover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseover) and [`mouseout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseout) **bubble** from descendants to their ancestors, so (for instance) if you have:

```
<div><span>foo</span> <span>bar</span></div>
```

...and you have a `mouseout` handler on the div, you'll get `mouseout` events as the mouse cursor travels out of the **spans** inside the div. Try it:

```js
document.querySelector(".example").addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  console.log("div received mouseover");
});
document.querySelector(".example").addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
  console.log("div received mouseout");
});
```

```css
div.example {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 4px;
}
div.example span {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="example"><span>foo</span> <span>bar</span></div>
```

If you want an event that doesn't bubble, use [`mouseenter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter) (for when the mouse enters that specific element) and [`mouseleave`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseleave) (for when it leaves that specific element). Try it:

```js
document.querySelector(".example").addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
  console.log("div received mouseenter");
});
document.querySelector(".example").addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
  console.log("div received mouseleave");
});
```

```css
div.example {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 4px;
}
div.example span {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="example"><span>foo</span> <span>bar</span></div>
```

Comment: Many Javascript events have this property, it's always a good idea to check if you need non-bubbling behavior. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_bubbles.asp

Comment: Ahh so bubbling is the thing that I was not understanding. Thanks a lot, I'll accept the answer as soon as I confirm that it is indeed the case here.